# Kendo UI , AutoComplete Max capacity is 1000. I want to increase this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

Hello Kendo UI users,

I came across a strange problem, where the CAPACITY of AUTOCOMPLETE is only upto 1000.

How do I increase it? because I need it for over 3000 values.

I checked for autocomplete function in kendo.all.min.js, with no success.

Any Help ?

Here is my code

```
var DS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
             type: "odata",                                                     
                    transport: {
                    read: {                             
                        url: "http://domain/news/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/translatorList/",                                
                        dataType: "json"                                
                        }                                
                   }
            });
 $("#translator").kendoAutoComplete({  
                dataTextField: "Deutsch",                       
                dataSource: DS,
                  change: function(e) {
                    var value = this.value();
                    $.getJSON("http://Domain/news/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/WZlist?$filter=startswith(Deutsch,'" + value + "')",function(d){
                        $('#res').val(d.d.results[0].Englisch);                             
                    });
                  }
              });
```

Comment: Please show your code. Also, if you have that many values, think about using server-based autocomplete, where you have no upper limit.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Server Filtering, as defined here:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/serverfiltering.html

This will allow you to do any filtering you need server side and return a minimal number of rows to the client.

Even the limit of 1,000 for client-side filtering is a bit much, in my opinion!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [pageSize](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/autocomplete/overview):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#autoComplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  minLength: 3,
  dataTextField: "Name", // JSON property name to use
  dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
   type: "odata", // specifies data protocol
   pageSize: 3000, // limits result set
   transport: {
    read: "http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles"
   }
  })
 })
});
```

Comment: Does not work Valery, I think paging has nothing to do with AutoComplete :P

Comment: Are you sure that more than 1000 items are returned from server side?

Comment: Good point, Here in my DOM, the results array is predefined to 1000, although my count is 2981.

 Object { results=[1000], __count="2981", __next="http://Domain.uni...llpages&$skiptoken=3368"}

Any idea how you can help ?

Comment: Try to set serverPaging to true (http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverPaging).